# Why promise not working in golang chromedp

Tags: go, promise, webdriver, chromedp

I was actually tried to execute this code in `golang chromedp`, but not working

```js
const inlineJavascript = `
    var textarea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textarea.setAttribute('id', 'recaptcha-token-container');
    textarea.style.display = 'display:none;'
    document.body.appendChild(textarea);

    grecaptcha.execute('SITE_KEY', { action: 'login' }).then(function(token) {
        textarea.value = token;
        textarea.style.display = ''
    });
`
```

```js
chromedp.EvaluateAsDevTools(inlineJavascript, &token),
chromedp.WaitVisible(`#recaptcha-token-container`),
chromedp.Value(`#recaptcha-token-container`, &token),
```

application wait for textarea, `.then` not working and textarea `never` showing.

Comment: I assume that SITE_KEY is set correctly. Does the snippet work when you paste it in your browsers' dev tools? You might also want to handle errors and display them somewhere you can see

Comment: @xarantolus `SITE_KEY` is modified, yes work fine in the devtools, but returns.

Comment: `log.Println(token)` returns `map[then:map[]]`

Answer (score 1):

[`WaitVisible`](https://godoc.org/github.com/chromedp/chromedp#WaitVisible) waits until your element is visible.

In your line `textarea.style.display = 'display:none;'`, the CSS style is invalid and thus ignored, which means that this is the point at which your element is visible.
The line should be

```
textarea.style.display = 'none'
```

So `WaitVisible` returns at the moment after `document.body.appendChild(textarea);` is run, which means that everything after it doesn't affect the `token`.

When you change the incorrect CSS, it should work since the element will only be made visible after the promise runs

Comment: Thanks @xarantolus, in fact `textarea` never been hidden and `WaitVisible` not waiting the element, it's problem is javascript `Promise`.

solution:
`
(async () => {
   var t = await grecaptcha.execute('SITE_KEY', { action: '%v' }).then(function(token) { return token; });
   textarea.value = t;
   textarea.style.display = ''
  })()
`